# adxl345 sample frequency too low stm23f4

Tags: stm32, freertos

Hi I'm trying to build a self balancing robot, so I need accelerometer and gyro but I can't set the maximum output frequency of the accelerometer. Currently with my code the time needed to get the angle is of almost 28ms that I think is too much. Do you have any suggestion to solve that?
The code that I attach is the one that I'm using to control the robot that's why the code is pretty long, but the functions that are used to communicate with the sensor are at the beginning of the file, while at the end there is the task (StartSampler)that use these function. I'm using a nucleo stm32f401re board with FreeRtos.

https://pastebin.com/suuePCrK

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * This notice applies to any and all portions of this file
  * that are not between comment pairs USER CODE BEGIN and
  * USER CODE END. Other portions of this file, whether 
  * inserted by the user or by software development tools
  * are owned by their respective copyright owners.
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2018 STMicroelectronics International N.V. 
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without 
  * modification, are permitted, provided that the following conditions are met:
  *
  * 1. Redistribution of source code must retain the above copyright notice, 
  *    this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
  * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
  *    this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
  *    and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
  * 3. Neither the name of STMicroelectronics nor the names of other 
  *    contributors to this software may be used to endorse or promote products 
  *    derived from this software without specific written permission.
  * 4. This software, including modifications and/or derivative works of this 
  *    software, must execute solely and exclusively on microcontroller or
  *    microprocessor devices manufactured by or for STMicroelectronics.
  * 5. Redistribution and use of this software other than as permitted under 
  *    this license is void and will automatically terminate your rights under 
  *    this license. 
  *
  * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY STMICROELECTRONICS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" 
  * AND ANY EXPRESS, IMPLIED OR STATUTORY WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT 
  * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A 
  * PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NON-INFRINGEMENT OF THIRD PARTY INTELLECTUAL PROPERTY
  * RIGHTS ARE DISCLAIMED TO THE FULLEST EXTENT PERMITTED BY LAW. IN NO EVENT 
  * SHALL STMICROELECTRONICS OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT,
  * INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
  * LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, 
  * OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF 
  * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING 
  * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE,
  * EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"
#include "cmsis_os.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "math.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim3;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart6;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_usart1_rx;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_usart6_rx;

osThreadId FilterHandle;
osThreadId ControllerHandle;
osThreadId ActuatorHandle;
osThreadId StampaHandle;
osThreadId SetPIDHandle;
osThreadId SamplerHandle;
osMutexId i2c_mutexHandle;
osMutexId uart_mutexHandle;
osMutexId sample_mutexHandle;
osMutexId pid_mutexHandle;
osMutexId angle_mutexHandle;
osMutexId voltage_mutexHandle;
osMutexId controller_mutexHandle;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
#define T                                       3                       //period 3 ms
#define T_control                       0.003               //period expressed in seconds 
#define N                                       1                       //number of samples 
#define adxl_address                0x53<<1
#define ITG3205_ADDRESS         0x68<<1

#define GRADSEC_TO_RAD          0.0174533       //°/s to radiant
#define RANGE                               0.0                 //range 
#define MAX_CONTROL                 6                       //max voltage to motors
#define CYCLE_CALIB                 2000
#define SOFT_START                  50
float OFFSET=0;

uint8_t acc_id, gyro_id;
int cnt=0; 

float OFFSET_ADX=-0.00196964317;
float OFFSET_GYRO=2.62438679;
float X_OFF=0;
float Y_OFF=0;
float Z_OFF=0;
float Y_GYR_OFF=-9.64649963;
int16_t x_u, y_u, z_u;
float x, y, z, y_g; 
int16_t y_gyro; 
int16_t y_gyro_old; 
uint8_t uart_buff[1]; 

uint8_t lsm6ds0_id; 
float acc_pitch, gyr_pitch;

char x_bt[4]; 
char y_bt[4]; 
char z_bt[4];
char yg_bt[4];

int m=0; 
int fine_pid=0;
int cr[4]={0,0,0,0};


//////WCET///////////
long unsigned int time[4]; 
long unsigned int time_sampler[4]; 
long unsigned int time_controller[4]; 
long unsigned int time_actuator[4]; 
long unsigned int time_stampa[4]; 


float adxl_pitch[N], itg3205_pitch[N];
float avg_adxl_pitch, avg_itg3205_pitch; 
float send_to_controller[2]; 
float send_to_actuator[2]; 


//CONTROLLER VARIABLE
double error, error_der, error_int, error_old; 
double control; 
double position=0, position_old=0; 
double KP=0;
double KI=0; 
double KD=0; 

double p_off=0;//0.072;
double n_off=0;//0.00085;

    double local_avg_adxl_pitch, local_avg_itg3205_pitch; 

//BLUETOOTH COMMUNICATION
uint8_t buff_rec[14+6+3];   //14 se il pid è costituito da 3 cifre intere 20 se p,i e d hanno due cifre decimali + 3 per i punti da saltare delle cifre decimali
char stamp[3];
uint8_t pid_vector[100];

int count=0;
uint32_t temp[10]; 

//CHECK SAMPLING TIME
float sensor_time;
TickType_t start_time=0;
TickType_t finish_time=0;


/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_USART6_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM3_Init(void);
void StarFilter(void const * argument);
void StartController(void const * argument);
void StartActuator(void const * argument);
void StartStampa(void const * argument);
void StartSetPID(void const * argument);
void StartSampler(void const * argument);

void HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim);


/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
uint8_t data_reg[22]; 
uint8_t data_gyro; 

void adxl_write(uint8_t reg, uint8_t value){
    uint8_t data[2]; 
    data[0]=reg; 
    data[1]=value; 
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, adxl_address, data, 2, 10); 
        temp[0]=temp[0]+1; 
}

void adxl_read(uint8_t reg, uint8_t numberOfByte){
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, adxl_address, reg, 1, data_reg, numberOfByte, 100);
temp[1]=temp[1]+1; 
}

void adxl_init(void ){
    adxl_read(0x00, 1); 
    acc_id=data_reg[0];
    adxl_write(0x2d, 0x00); //reset all bits
    //aggiunto per problemi sui registri alti dei sensori 
    adxl_write(0x2c, 0x0F);
    adxl_write(0x2d, 0x08); //measure bit-1, wake up 0, 0 at 8Mhz
    adxl_write(0x31, 0x03); //+-16g range  0x01 come secondo parametro per 4g range
    adxl_write(0x38, 0x80); //bypass filter fifo
}

void adxl_get_values(void){
        temp[2]=temp[2]+1; 
        adxl_read(0x32,6); 
        //l'aggiunta del -0.04 o -0.08 è per l'offset del sensore
        x_u=((data_reg[1]<<8) | data_reg[0])-0.04;//+1.74;      
        y_u=((data_reg[3]<<8) | data_reg[2])-0.04;//+1.74; 
        z_u=((data_reg[5]<<8) | data_reg[4])-0.08;//-3.73; 

        x=x_u*0.0312;                                                                                                                               //31.2/1000(mg) to scale to g
        y=y_u*0.0312;                                                                                                                               //31.2/1000(mg) to scale to g
        z=z_u*0.0312;                                                                                                                               //31.2/1000(mg) to scale to g

        sprintf(x_bt, "%f", x);             
        sprintf(y_bt, "%f", y); 
        sprintf(y_bt, "%f", z); 
}

float adxl_get_roll(void){
    adxl_get_values();
    return atan2(y, sqrt(x*x+z*z))*57.32484;
}

float adxl_get_pitch_rad(void){
    adxl_get_values();
    return atan2(x, sqrt(y*y+z*z));
}

float adxl_get_pitch(void){
    return (adxl_get_pitch_rad()-OFFSET)*57.32484;
}

void adxl_calib(void){
        for(int i=0; i<CYCLE_CALIB; i++){
            OFFSET=adxl_get_pitch_rad();
            HAL_Delay(T/N);
        }
    OFFSET/=CYCLE_CALIB;
}

void itg3205_write(uint8_t reg, uint8_t value){
    uint8_t data[2]; 
    data[0]=reg; 
    data[1]=value;
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, ITG3205_ADDRESS, data, 2, 10); 
}

void itg3205_read(uint8_t reg, uint8_t numberOfByte){
HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, ITG3205_ADDRESS, reg, 1, &data_gyro, numberOfByte, 100);
}


void itg3205_init(void){
    uint8_t value[2];
    itg3205_read(0x00, 1); 
    gyro_id=data_gyro; 

    //SET FULL SCALE +- 2000°/s
    itg3205_write(0x16, 0x18);
}

float itg3205_get_pitch(void){
    itg3205_read(0x20, 1); 
    y_gyro=data_gyro;
    itg3205_read(0x1F, 1); 
    y_gyro |=(data_gyro<<8);
    return (y_gyro/14.375); 
}

void itg3205_calib(void){
    for(int i=0; i<CYCLE_CALIB; i++){
        OFFSET_GYRO+=itg3205_get_pitch();
        HAL_Delay(20);
    }
    OFFSET_GYRO/=CYCLE_CALIB;
}


void acc_calib(void){
      OFFSET_ADX=0;
        for(int i=0; i<CYCLE_CALIB; i++){
            OFFSET_ADX+=adxl_get_pitch_rad();
            HAL_Delay(T/N);
        }
    OFFSET_ADX/=CYCLE_CALIB;
}
void gyr_calib(void){
    OFFSET_GYRO=0; 
    for(int i=0; i<CYCLE_CALIB; i++){
        OFFSET_GYRO+=itg3205_get_pitch();
        HAL_Delay(20);
    }
    OFFSET_GYRO/=CYCLE_CALIB;
}
/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  *
  * @retval None
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_USART6_UART_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
    //HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart6,buff_rec,14+6+3);    //struttura predefinita con 5 valori + punto piu lettere + spazio es 'p100.20 i0.0000 d0.0000'
    HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart6,buff_rec, 1); 
    adxl_init();
    itg3205_init();
    //acc_axis_calib();
    //gyr_axis_calib();
    //acc_calib();
    //gyr_calib();
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_2); 
    __HAL_TIM_SetCompare(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_2, 250);
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim3);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Create the mutex(es) */
  /* definition and creation of i2c_mutex */
  osMutexDef(i2c_mutex);
  i2c_mutexHandle = osMutexCreate(osMutex(i2c_mutex));

  /* definition and creation of uart_mutex */
  osMutexDef(uart_mutex);
  uart_mutexHandle = osMutexCreate(osMutex(uart_mutex));

  /* definition and creation of sample_mutex */
  osMutexDef(sample_mutex);
  sample_mutexHandle = osMutexCreate(osMutex(sample_mutex));

  /* definition and creation of pid_mutex */
  osMutexDef(pid_mutex);
  pid_mutexHandle = osMutexCreate(osMutex(pid_mutex));

  /* definition and creation of angle_mutex */
  osMutexDef(angle_mutex);
  angle_mutexHandle = osMutexCreate(osMutex(angle_mutex));

  /* definition and creation of voltage_mutex */
  osMutexDef(voltage_mutex);
  voltage_mutexHandle = osMutexCreate(osMutex(voltage_mutex));

  /* definition and creation of controller_mutex */
  osMutexDef(controller_mutex);
  controller_mutexHandle = osMutexCreate(osMutex(controller_mutex));

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_MUTEX */
  /* add mutexes, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_MUTEX */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_SEMAPHORES */
  /* add semaphores, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_SEMAPHORES */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_TIMERS */
  /* start timers, add new ones, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_TIMERS */

  /* Create the thread(s) */
  /* definition and creation of Filter */
  //osThreadDef(Filter, StarFilter, osPriorityRealtime, 0, 128);
  //FilterHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(Filter), NULL);

  /* definition and creation of Controller */
  osThreadDef(Controller, StartController, osPriorityRealtime, 0, 128);
  ControllerHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(Controller), NULL);

  /* definition and creation of Actuator */
  osThreadDef(Actuator, StartActuator, osPriorityRealtime, 0, 128);
  ActuatorHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(Actuator), NULL);

  /* definition and creation of Stampa */
  //osThreadDef(Stampa, StartStampa, osPriorityLow, 0, 128);
  //StampaHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(Stampa), NULL);

  /* definition and creation of SetPID */
  //osThreadDef(SetPID, StartSetPID, osPriorityLow, 0, 128);
  //SetPIDHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(SetPID), NULL);

  /* definition and creation of Sampler */
  osThreadDef(Sampler, StartSampler, osPriorityRealtime, 0, 128);
  SamplerHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(Sampler), NULL);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_THREADS */
  /* add threads, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_THREADS */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_QUEUES */
  /* add queues, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_QUEUES */


  /* Start scheduler */
  osKernelStart();

  /* We should never get here as control is now taken by the scheduler */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
            while (1)
  {
  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

    /**Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
    */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE2);

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 84;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 15, 0);
}

/* I2C1 init function */
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 400000;
  hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/* TIM2 init function */
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC;

  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 84;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 1000;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 500;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim2);

}

/* TIM3 init function */
static void MX_TIM3_Init(void)
{

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;

  htim3.Instance = TIM3;
  htim3.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim3.Init.Period = 65535;
  htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim3, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/* USART1 init function */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/* USART6 init function */
static void MX_USART6_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart6.Instance = USART6;
  huart6.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart6.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart6.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart6.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart6.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart6.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart6.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart6) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/** 
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void) 
{
  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA2_Stream1_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Stream1_IRQn, 5, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Stream1_IRQn);
  /* DMA2_Stream2_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Stream2_IRQn, 5, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Stream2_IRQn);

}

/** Configure pins as 
        * Analog 
        * Input 
        * Output
        * EVENT_OUT
        * EXTI
*/
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PA4 PA5 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_5;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
  /* Prevent unused argument(s) compilation warning */
  UNUSED(huart);
  /* NOTE: This function Should not be modified, when the callback is needed,
           the HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback could be implemented in the user file
   */
            ///da un'array di numeri sotto forma di caratteri mi porto a un intero a 3cifre
            /*
            KP=(double)(100*(buff_rec[1]-48)+10*(buff_rec[2]-48)+1*(buff_rec[3]-48)+0.01*(buff_rec[5]-48)+0.001*(buff_rec[6]-48));
            KI=(double)(1*(buff_rec[9]-48)+0.1*(buff_rec[11]-48)+0.01*(buff_rec[12]-48)+0.001*(buff_rec[13]-48)+0.0001*(buff_rec[14]-48));
            KD=(double)(1*(buff_rec[17]-48)+0.1*(buff_rec[19]-48)+0.01*(buff_rec[20]-48)+0.001*(buff_rec[21]-48)+0.0001*(buff_rec[22]-48));
        */
        char delim[]=" ";
        if(buff_rec[0]!='\n'){
            //ancora devo ricevere l'ultimo carattere
            pid_vector[m]=buff_rec[0];
            m++;}
            else {
                //ultimo carattere ricevuto 

                //creo vettore di pari dimensione e lo riempio 
                uint8_t *tempo_buffer=malloc(m*sizeof(uint8_t));
                strcpy((char *)tempo_buffer,(const char *) pid_vector);
                char *ptr = strtok((char *)tempo_buffer, delim);
                KP = atof(ptr);
                ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
                KI = atof(ptr);
                ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
                KD = atof(ptr);

                //pulisco i puntatori
                free(ptr);
                free(tempo_buffer);
                for (int k=0; k<=m; k++)
                    pid_vector[k]=0; 
                m=0;
                        }



    /*
    //per trasformare l'intero p in un arrai di char cosi da stamparlo
            if(uart_mutexHandle !=NULL){
                if(xSemaphoreTake(uart_mutexHandle, (TickType_t) 5) == pdTRUE){
                    sprintf(stamp, "%f", KP);
                    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart6, (uint8_t *)"P: ", 3,10);
                    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart6, (uint8_t *) stamp, 3, 10); 
                    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart6, (uint8_t *)"\n\r", 2, 10);

                    sprintf(stamp, "%f", KI);
                    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart6, (uint8_t *)"I: ", 3,10);
                    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart6, (uint8_t *)stamp, 3, 10); 
                    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart6, (uint8_t *)"\n\r", 2, 10);

                    sprintf(stamp, "%f", KD);
                    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart6, (uint8_t *)"D: ", 3,10);
                    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart6, (uint8_t *)stamp, 3, 10); 
                    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart6, (uint8_t *)"\n\r", 2, 10);
                    xSemaphoreGive(uart_mutexHandle);
                }
            }
    vTaskResume(SetPIDHandle);
    */
}
/* USER CODE END 4 */

/* StarFilter function */
void StarFilter(void const * argument)
{
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Like the proverbial needle in the haystack, you’ve made it hard for people to find the error in your code. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: oh thanks georgeawg, i'm really new, I've tried to insert it in the correct way, I'll read the source you gave me. Many thanks